# Laravel Route resource destroy not working

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my form :

```
<form action="{{ route('invoice.destroy' , $invoice->id)}}" method="DELETE">
              <div class="modal-footer no-border">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
               <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />

              </div>
              </form>
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
    if(!$invoice){
        return redirect()->route('invoice.index')->with(['fail' => 'Page not found !']);
    }
    $invoice->delete();
    return redirect()->route('invoice.index')->with(['success' => 'Invoice Deleted.']);
}
```

But it can not delete where is the problem ? How solve this ?

Comment: You do not have hidden param named _method. Use Form::open().

Comment: Not using Form::open . i want to solved by this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `POST` method for the form and add `input` element with name  `_method` and value `DELETE`. Also, add token:

```
<form action="{{ route('invoice.destroy' , $invoice->id)}}" method="POST">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="modal-footer no-border">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes ,,,it's working . thank you so much @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: For edit you should use `Get`, but I guess what you need is `update` action, not `edit` (`edit` is just displays a form). For `update` you should use `Put` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must add a hidden input to the form which will contain the method used:

```
<form action="{{ route('invoice.destroy' , $invoice->id)}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
</form>
```

Read more on Laravel documentation about [Form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: Notice that the method of the form will be POST not DELETE

Answer (score 1):

More Laravel way you can do this

```
<form action="{{ route('invoice.destroy',$invoice->id)}}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
</form>
```

Comment: or @method('delete') in later versions

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `PUT` and `DELETE` methods to work, you need an additional field, since only `POST` and `GET` are possible within HTML (out-of-the-box).

The additional field will be made with the code:

```
{!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
```

So your form will look like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('invoice.destroy' , $invoice->id)}}" method="DELETE">
    {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
    <div class="modal-footer no-border">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by {{ method_field('DELETE') }} ??

Comment: WIth `{!! method_field('DELETE') !!}` (with exclamation marks) Laravel will make an additional hidden input file. When submittin the form, Laravel knows that the method is DELETE, executing `Route::delete()`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using blade templates, you can add the method field like so:
@method('DELETE')